How to run a local Open Source LLM in llama-index in a restricted environment?
I have a question on how to best run a local LLM (all Open Source) with llama-index for a RAG in a relatively restricted environment (absolutely no API calls, no installing from external GitRepos and also no Ollama or vLLM - which basically covers all I have experience with so far and all the examples I have come across...)
My approach is now to just load the quantized model with AWQ and then pass it to the query_engine, however, HuggingfaceLLM does not seem to support a locally stored model?
My specific question is, if I load a model like this:
from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_name_or_path = "local path to folder/model"

# Load model
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_quantized(model_name_or_path, fuse_layers=True,trust_remote_code=False, safetensors=True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, trust_remote_code=False)


then how do i proceed to further integrating this to llama-index? Do I need to write a custom LLM class?
Is there any other option on how to achieve this? Hardware won't be a problem, my question is on the best method to include the model.
Thanks in advance!

You could maybe use the LlamaFile project from Mozilla.

My recomendation is to use ollama and get yourself familair with it.
check their library for existing LLMS and their guides,,you can add an llm model of your choosing. just follow the guides in their documentation
heres their repo: https://github.com/ollama/ollama
the website :https://ollama.com/
the llamaIndex page for Ollama example for llama3 :https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/llm/ollama/

Thank you for getting back to me - unfortunately, I cannot use Ollama or anything similar in this setting, I have to load the model directly from file.
